# How can we use Service Oriented Architecture to automate the process of an application for fintech solution?

Tags: web-services, architecture, soa

I need, what is the fintech solution?, What are the processes of SOA?, How can i use SOA in fintech. I have started like this:

> "Fin Tech (Financial Technology) is a service innovation in financial
> services with a touch of modern technology.
>
> The types of Fin Tech
> services are very diverse, ranging from banking, asset management,
> e-money, P2P lending, payment gateway, remittance, stocks, and
> insurance coverage. Along with the development of existing Fin Tech
> startups, many investors, both individuals and institutions, aim at
> starting up Fin Tech companies as a source of investment.
>
> Also, the
> demand to create an integration between businesses and banking
> activities is growing, due to the increasing complexity of business
> processes and activities that evolved to make the use of Fin Tech
> applications."

Can you finish it?

Comment: Please reshape your question so that it follows the SO [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need help with a homework assignment?

The question is less about FinTech and more about SOA, specifically to see what understanding you have of SOA.  If you don't know anything about an information technology subject, like SOA, then Wikipedia is usually not a bad place **to start**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

> A service (the 'S' in SOA) is a discrete unit of functionality that can be accessed
> remotely and acted upon and updated independently, such as retrieving
> a credit card statement online.

So the "processes" your question is referring to will probably be how you go about understanding your problem domain (FinTech, or P2P Lending, etc) and then designing a set of services (the discrete units of functionality) that represent it.

"How can I use SOA in fintech" is basically asking you to explain the advantages of SOA, by talking about them in the context of FinTech (using FinTech examples).  So if you can understand a couple of the key advantages of SOA then this should be fairly easy.

Here's one of the advantages, to quote the wikipedia page again:

> A service presents a simple interface to the requester that abstracts
> away the underlying complexity acting as a black box.

There's two advantages here.  One of them is to make it easier for consumers to use the service, by making it's interface cleaner & simpler.  This usually implies trying to remove as many dependencies as possible.

The broader theme here is to try and manage complexity.

Hope that helps.  Generally speaking, people here won't do your homework for you, but are very happy to help clarify things you don't understand - as long as you can frame it as a 'question' that can be answered as per the site guidelines.